# Read Connection String into configuration without Entity Framewiork DbContext

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm developing a .NET Core 2.1 application that does not use Entity Framework.  But I'm wondering how to read the connection string into the Configuration because the usual method expects a DBContext file (which I do not have because I am note using EF).

If I were using EF, I would normally read the connection string from appsettings.json like this:

```
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

How do I do it without the DBContext?

Comment: @KirkLarkin -  System.Data.SqlClient.  I have written my own data access classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using simple ado.net, you can't use DBContext. You open a connection and execute your query instead:

**NOTE** using statement is important here to ensure the connection is disposed/closed properly.

```
 using (SqlConnection connection =
            new SqlConnection(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")))
        {
            // Create the Command and Parameter objects.
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pricePoint", paramValue);

            // Open the connection in a try/catch block. 
            // Create and execute the DataReader, writing the result
            // set to the console window.
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}\t{2}",
                        reader[0], reader[1], reader[2]);
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: I should have checked this.  The connection string is already read into the configuration.  Anything added to 'appsettings.json' is by default.  Thanks for your help, @AmanB